# Why is my expo serve using http://localhost:8081 instead of exp+fomo-app://expo-development-client/?

Tags: react-native, expo

My expo app keeps starting on `localhost:8081` I've tried changing the port to `8000` and `19000` via `npx expo start --port` but no luck, I also tried tunnel and still my `dev-client` kept saying "Could not load app: Could not connect to the server." Not exactly sure why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this issue when I removed

```
<data android:scheme="exp+[My app]"/>
```

from my AndroidManifest.xml file, adding it back solved the issue.

Comment: As I am using expo, I don't have access to this.

Comment: @Katharsin that’s because you’re on expo’s managed workflow. You can only update this in the bare workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to use `expo start` instead of `npx expo start` but this is deprecated.